# valor de select em array

Tags: php, array, select

Boas,

Olhando esta query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select A, B, C, D from table");
$row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Quero pegar na coluna A e colocar todos os valores numa array:

```
$var = array('value1','value2','value3','value4');
```

Qual a melhor forma de o fazer?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `while`.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select A, B, C, D from table");

while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $arrData[] = $res['A'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrData);
echo '</pre>'
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, e resultou, mas o primeiro valor não aparece.

Supondo de que o resultado seria:

valor1,
valor2,
valor3,
etc...

Comment: Você está repetindo o `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` não está ?

Comment: Não, é único no código.

<?php 
   $sql = mysql_query("select A from tableA where B IN($Var)");
   while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
   $arrData[] = $res['A'];
   }   
   #echo '<pre>';
   print_r(implode(',',$arrData));
   #echo '</pre>'
   ;?>

Comment: Atualize seu post com o código atual e com o retorno do código.

Comment: Refiz o código e tudo funcionou direitinho. Devia ter algo que não encontrei a impactar o resultado. Obrigado.